# Don't see the logic in putting functions as (arguments) instead of {do something}

Tags: jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery and need help to see the logic in this example:
If I want to hide a div on a click event the correct solution look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('div').click(function() {
         $('div').hide();
     });
});
```

But for me it would have made more sense if it looked like this:

```
$(document).ready() {
   $('div').click() {
       $('div').hide();    
   };
};
```

Hope someone understands why I find this confusing and can explain what I'm clearly missing out.

Comment: Well, maybe you can create another js-based language. ECMAScript 6 introduces [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions).

Comment: You probably like Coffeescript, then.

Comment: Refer [Javascript Tip Do Not Pollute Global Namespace With Utility Functions](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/03/18/javascript-tip-do-not-pollute-global-namespace-with-utility-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for great help!
It all boiled down to that my misconception was because I did not realize the difference between calling and declaring functions.

Calling: `function();`

Declaring: `function(){};`

Sorry for my confusing question, guess it wont be the last one ;)
Best regards,
Kristofer

Answer (score 3):

UI programming is by its nature [Event driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

In this paradigm, and regardless of the language you use, you must define event handlers that will be run when the event happens.
In your example it is more expressive if you use a less compact syntax:

```
$('div').on('click', reaction);
```

In pure OOP (for example java) **reaction** would be an object implementing a particular interface:

```
import java.util.Observer;
public class ResponseHandler implements Observer {
  ...
}
ResponseHandler reaction = new ResponseHandler();
```

Now, wellcome to Javascript !

As Javascript functions are [Higher-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), passing functions as arguments is a common practice and these are named [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29). And also javascript is very verbose when it comes to define this callback functions.

You must use the full function expression to define a callback (named or anonymous). Or you can move to Coffescript cosmetics to skim these function definitions (but they are just syntax sugar because function definition is present anyway).

Your invented {} syntax or coffescript arrow syntax is in fact hiding the actual **reaction**.

```
$('div').on('click', reaction);
```

**reaction** in javascript is just a function, a callback function.

Now, jQuery events are an implementation of a [reactor engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern), allowing your application code to be completely separated from the actual engine. And this means that a jQuery application is a group of definitions of reactions to events:

- whenever document is ready, do this.
- whenever user clicks on div, do that.
- whenever mouse enters span, do whatever.

Answer (score 2):

What you're actually seeing is the use of callbacks, you can either pass an anonymous function or the name of a predefined function in.

```
$('div').click( // Callback within scope of selector when event is fired );
```

You could also do something like:

```
function doStuff() {
    console.log('doing stuff...');
}

$('div').click('doStuff');
```

If you were to use your example and do $('div').click() it would actually trigger the click event on the div.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the anonymous function is that it is called inside the ready function. This way jQuery can perform some actions before and after calling the function you pass to the ready function.
Of course jQuery.ready function is much more complex, but to illustrate what I mean, let's pretend it is:

```
jQuery.ready = function(yourAnonymusFunction) {
    // do something before ...

    // call the function you passed
    yourAnonymusFunction();

    // do something afterwards

}
```

With your syntax, which in fact should be:

```
$(document).ready = function() {
    $('div').click() {
    $('div').hide();    
};
```

you would overwrite the ready function.

Answer (score 1):

I think your concern is more related to syntax rather than to the logic.

you should really check the [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) out

your code would look like this

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("div").click ->
    $("div").hide()
```

however CoffeScript is more like template language that needs to be compiled to JavaScript (which is easy to do ). But the benefits are worth the extra trouble with compiling. :)

try it out here http://js2coffee.org/

Comment: also if you're working with web-framework Ruby on Rails, from version 3.1 (I think) framework will compile your CoffeeScript assets automatically to JS

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous function are used to avoid polluting the global namespace

Suppose

1)

```
var x="test"
   function a(){
   alert(x);//  x then its global to whole script available to the page
   }
```

2) if u define

```
  function () {
      var x="test"
      function a(){
      alert(x); //will bo local to this anonymous function and will not pollute the global x variable and still global for methods inside this anonympous function.
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `ready` takes a function as an argument. when the function `ready` executes, all it does is add that function to a the list of functions to be executed when the element is ready. This is known as a [call-back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

Therefore, in your code you need to define a function, then pass that function to `$.ready`. Javascript is totally dynamic and has no way to know that `ready` itself is a function which accepts a function as an argument, this is why you need to use a syntax which specifies "call ready as a function, passing in this block of code which I am now defining as a function".

Having said that, this is a very common pattern in javascript and there is a lot of pressure to make the sytax more terse.